# Unenroll from Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

With [Android Management Quickstart](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb) I have created an enterprise and associated it with a Google Cloud Platform project using [signupUrls.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/signupUrls/create) and [enterprises.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises/create).

When trying to create another enterprise with a different EMM provider I get an error message saying I'm already enrolled with an EMM provider.

How can I delete the previous enterprise (or unenroll) so that I can enroll with the other EMM provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an enterprise:

1. Visit [play.google.com/work](http://play.google.com/work) with the account used to create the
   enterprise.
2. Select **Admin Settings**.
3. In Organization information, select the three vertical dots.
4. Click **Delete Organization**.

This is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart#2_delete_an_enterprise).